# Audio URI `gc://...` is an invalid GCS path

Tags: java, google-speech-to-text-api

Help me please if you can)
I am trying to use google speech to text API. I have uploaded an audio file ( record1638730550724.wav) on google storage bucket with the name "summaryapp". But when i try to make longrecognize request i get this error

> 2021-12-05 18:56:20 INFO  RecordController:60 -
> com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException:
> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Audio URI
> `gc://summaryapp/record1638730255219.wav` is an invalid GCS path.

RecognizeRequestHandler class:

```
    public class RecognizeRequestHandler {


    private static CallsInfo callsInfo;
    @Autowired
    private static CallsInfoDaoImpl callsInfoDao;

    public static void asyncRecognizeGcs(String gcsUri, int oid) throws Exception {
        // Configure polling algorithm
        SpeechSettings.Builder speechSettings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder();
        TimedRetryAlgorithm timedRetryAlgorithm =
                OperationTimedPollAlgorithm.create(
                        RetrySettings.newBuilder()
                                .setInitialRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(500L))
                                .setRetryDelayMultiplier(1.5)
                                .setMaxRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(5000L))
                                .setInitialRpcTimeout(Duration.ZERO) // ignored
                                .setRpcTimeoutMultiplier(1.0) // ignored
                                .setMaxRpcTimeout(Duration.ZERO) // ignored
                                .setTotalTimeout(Duration.ofHours(24L)) // set polling timeout to 24 hours
                                .build());
        speechSettings.longRunningRecognizeOperationSettings().setPollingAlgorithm(timedRetryAlgorithm);

        // Instantiates a client with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
        try (SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create(speechSettings.build())) {

            // Configure remote file request for FLAC
            RecognitionConfig config =
                    RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                            .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                            .setLanguageCode("ru-RU")
                            .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                            .build();
            RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(gcsUri).build();

            // Use non-blocking call for getting file transcription
            OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata> response =
                    speech.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio);
            while (!response.isDone()) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }

            List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.get().getResultsList();

            for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
                // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
                // first (most likely) one here.
                SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
                System.out.printf("Transcription: %s\n", alternative.getTranscript());

                //Trying to write response to database
                Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                String text = alternative.getTranscript();
                callsInfo = new CallsInfo(oid, date, text);
                callsInfoDao.create(callsInfo);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And this is RecordController class, which call Recognize class with GCS URL

```
public class RecordController {

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RecordController.class);

    @Autowired
    AuthToken authToken;

    @Autowired
    AuthTokenDaoImpl authTokenDao;

    @Autowired
    AudioRecord audioRecord;

    @Autowired
    RecordDaoImpl recordDao;

    Thread t;

    private String RESULT = "NO MATCHING";
    private String GCS_URL = "gc://summaryapp/";
    private String RECORD_FILE_NAME = "";

    @PostMapping(value = "/newAudioRecord", consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    public String postNewRecord(@RequestParam(value = "token", required = true) String token,
                                @RequestBody AudioRecord audioRecord) throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(audioRecord.getOid() + " " + audioRecord.getRecordFileName());
        authToken = authTokenDao.readByToken(token);
        if (authToken != null) {
            RECORD_FILE_NAME = audioRecord.getRecordFileName();
            audioRecord.setOid(authToken.getOid());
            recordDao.create(audioRecord);
            AudioRecord resultAudioRecord = recordDao.readByName(audioRecord.getOid(),
                    audioRecord.getRecordFileName());
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            RESULT = mapper.writeValueAsString(resultAudioRecord);

                  try {
                      RecognizeRequestHandler.asyncRecognizeGcs(GCS_URL+RECORD_FILE_NAME, audioRecord.getOid());
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      logger.info(e.getMessage());
                  }
        }
        return RESULT;
    }
}
```

**UPD:** After changing gc:// to gs:// in path i am do not get any messages about "invalid path". But now process ends with following lines in logs:

> 2021-12-06 18:37:34 INFO  RecognizeRequestHandler:108 - -------->
> Result list size: 0 2021-12-06 18:37:34 DEBUG NettyClientHandler:214 -
> [id: 0xa576e0da, L:/172.18.0.2:49394 -
> R:speech.googleapis.com/64.233.164.95:443] OUTBOUND GO_AWAY:
> lastStreamId=0 errorCode=0 length=0 bytes= 2021-12-06 18:37:35 DEBUG
> PoolThreadCache:229 - Freed 24 thread-local buffer(s) from thread:
> grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-4

As seen from "sout debug" - line of code

```
List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.get().getResultsList();
```

returns a result list size: 0

--------> Result list size: 0

**UPD:** Audio recorded with next settings:

```
int mic = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
        recorder.setAudioSource(mic);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]); //MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(encoder); //MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(sampleRate); //16000
        recorder.setOutputFile(CurrentAudioFilePath);
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
        recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
```

Comment: Just curious, doesn't GCS use URL starting with `gs://`?

Comment: me curious too) but in many examples path specify as gs://

Comment: Can you specify `gs://summaryapp/record1638730255219.wav` instead of `gc://summaryapp/record1638730255219.wav` and try it?

Comment: thanks! now i am do not have any messages about invalid path, but now i still not get any recognize result - see UPD above.